# how to check is some specific word in listbox selected item?

Tags: vb.net

I tried:

1. If ListBox1.Items.Contains("myword") Then
2. If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf("myword") Then
3. If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Item("myword") Then

but no efect.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, the [listbox.items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) Property is an [ListBox.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx):

```
For Each i As Object In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    If CStr(i).Contains("myword") Then
        BackColor = Color.Blue ' Do your logic here, I just used setting the BackColor for a test
    End If
Next
```